# How to prevent author of Git commit from being changed

Tags: git, commit, author

I want to make distinct users for my Git commits. For example, now we have 5 systems installed with Git. But while committing a change into Git remote  repository, I can change my default author name and email in commit window.

How can I make it so they cannot be changed?

Comment: i don't think you can. Maybe (really maybe) you can do something with git hooks (https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), or by signing commits (https://help.github.com/articles/signing-commits-using-gpg/ and http://pedrorijo.com/blog/git-gpg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Git repository is *yours*.  You can do *anything you want* to it.  No one else can stop you, and you cannot stop anyone else from doing anything *they* want to *their* repositories.

In short, there is nothing—literally nothing—you can to do prevent someone else from claiming to be you, or to prevent yourself from claiming to be someone else.  This is the same problem a bank ATM has.  In order to make sure you are *you*, and Fred is Fred, and so on, you must step outside the problem itself and look to *authentication*.  If someone *claims* to be Fred, how do you know whether he is or is not Fred?  Especially, how can you tell whether he's really Fred if you've never met him before?  He might be Ravi, or Binyamin, or Jürgen!

If you and Fred have a shared secret, or some other way of *deciding* whether to believe him, you can use that.  And that's *all* you can do: decide, at the time you are obtaining some set of commits from someone, whether or not you believe them when they tell you they're Fred.

Git has GPG signature verification built in, to some extent (it does not do the GPG signature stuff itself, it relies on third-party software).  You can sign individual commits, or sign an annotated tag.  For a bunch of good reasons, signing individual commits is usually more cost than benefit.  Git commits form a [Merkle Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree), so checking the signature of an annotated tag provides a reasonable level of assurance about the commits reachable from that tag.  (The amount of protection, however, is not much greater than that of SHA-1.)  See also [GPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard).

Answer (score 1):

As you are committing you can set the author of each commit

```
git commit -m "Your commit message" --author="Author Name <author.name@example.com>"
```

I've included the `-m` flag for this example, but you could exclude it and set the commit message in your favourite editor.

This is presuming you're using the CLI, if you're using a GUI/IDE let me know and I'll see if I can find how to use author setting in that.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the OP's question. They are asking how they can _prevent_ committers from changing author information.

Comment: @DanLowe I answered the question as I interpreted the wording at the time - it has since been changed by edit.